# Transparently tunnel HTTPS using squid with SNI filtering

Tags: squid

My requirements are:

1. The proxy should be transparent.
2. I should be able to filter websites by domain name.
3. I do *not* want to decrypt traffic. I'm looking for an SNI sniffing based solution -- no installing certificates on clients.

There are plenty of answers floating around but they are either incorrect (claiming you need to decrypt traffic in order to do this) or incomplete.

Answer (score 8):

The way to do this is to use the ssl peek feature introduced in Squid 3.5. See [here](https://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/SslPeekAndSplice) for a detailed explanation. Do note you will need to have compiled with either `--with-gnutls` or `--with-openssl` (check `squid -v`). Some distros leave them out.

In short, the relevant squid configuration looks like this.

```
acl denylist_ssl ssl::server_name google.com # NOT dstdomain
acl step1 at_step SslBump1
ssl_bump peek step1
ssl_bump splice !denylist_ssl # allow everything not in the denylist
ssl_bump terminate all # block everything else
https_port 3129 intercept ssl-bump cert=/etc/squid/dummy.pem
```

(Aside: I am not sure why we need to only peek at step 1 and not step 2 given that step 2 involves only receiving the server certificate. The docs do not make this clear at all. Using `ssl_bump peek all` as they recommend makes this stop working entirely).

And then do the usual redirect port 443 to 3129 dance using iptables (or have squid listen on 443 directly if you prefer).

```
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3129
```

You can use any certificate for the dummy, we actually never use it (because we're not decrypting traffic).

Something like this works.

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:4096 -sha256 -days 365 -nodes -x509 -keyout dummy.pem -out dummy.pem
```

---

Sources:

[1] https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/613359/setting-up-squid-transparent-proxy-with-ssl-bumping-on-debian-10

[2] https://web.archive.org/web/20210128152111/https://www.cammckenzie.com/blog/index.php/2018/07/19/squid-https-interception-and-filtering-without-client-certificates/

[3] https://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/SslPeekAndSplice

Comment: "some distros" is actually closer to "most distros", the Debian-based ones all leave them out and IIRC, RHEL and derivatives do too. That leaves mostly niche distros to provide them, Alpine being maybe the most popular distro to provide it considering its use in containers.

Comment: @Ginnungagap I'm running CentOS 7.9 and my squid does come with openssl.

Comment: Ah, so I didn't recall correctly, thanks for the info :)

Comment: Might be of some help too https://docs.diladele.com/tutorials/transparent_proxy_debian/index.html